# Publish to specific Observer using PublishSubject

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a `ViewPager` with two pages namely **Popular** and **All**. What I'm trying to achieve is only push items that have popular tag true to **Popular** whereas push all items to **All**.

Currently I have a single class which is used in the `PagerAdapter` and passing in the page type. How do I filter out `PublishSubject` so that each page only displays necessary items accordingly.

> Both my Observer are subscribed to a single `PublishSubject`, but I
>   want to filter when emitting.

Please comment if the question is unclear. I'll try my best to relay this problem. Also sorry if it has already been answered since I couldn't find anything relevant.

The code I'm using is [this](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) based on [this architecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) in which I have a Firebase data store [FirebaseSubscriptionDataStore](https://github.com/riteshakya037/Subs/blob/master/data/src/main/java/io/subs/data/repository/datasource/subscriptions/FirebaseSubscriptionDataStore.java) which provides the `PublishSubject`. This is later subscribed to by [SubscribeToSubscriptionUpdates](https://github.com/riteshakya037/Subs/blob/master/domain/src/main/java/io/subs/domain/usecases/subscription/SubscribeToSubscriptionUpdates.java) in [SubscriptionListPresenterImpl](https://github.com/riteshakya037/Subs/blob/master/presentation/src/main/java/io/subs/android/views/screens/add_subscription/SubscriptionListPresenterImpl.java)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some code, especially parts of PagerAdapter where you subscribe to subject.

Comment: PagerAdapter dosen't have anything relevant. I'm subscribing to the aforementioned `PublishSubject` in onCreateView of `Fragment` which is bound to the `ViewPager`

Comment: How do you provide data from parent fragment to fragments in your `ViewPager`?

Comment: I have added reference to the whole codebase and linked relevant classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically define two different methods to get `Observable` (or Flowable) from `PublishSubject`. First observable will emit all of the items and second one only popular ones:

```
public class DataStore {

    private PublishSubject<DataItem> dataItemPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    public Flowable<DataItem> getAllObservable() {
        return dataItemPublishSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    }

    public Flowable<DataItem> getPopularObservable() {
        return dataItemPublishSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                .filter(new Predicate<DataItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(DataItem dataItem) throws Exception {
                        return dataItem.popular;
                    }
                });
    }

    public static class DataItem {
        public final boolean popular;

        public DataItem(boolean popular) {
            this.popular = popular;
        }
    }
}
```

In case you don't want to two methods, you can move `.filter()` operator everywhere within you Rx chain and you might end up with something like this:

```
    dataStore.getAllObservable()
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<DataStore.DataItem>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(DataStore.DataItem dataItem) throws Exception {
                    pagerAdapter.addDataAll(dataItem);      
                }
            })
            .filter(new Predicate<DataStore.DataItem>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(DataStore.DataItem dataItem) throws Exception {
                    return dataItem.popular;
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<DataStore.DataItem>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(DataStore.DataItem dataItem) throws Exception {
                    pagerAdapter.addDataPopular(dataItem);
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: I guess there no pretty way to do this besides the first solution. Thanks for the updates.